# What do two parameters do in a ".append" in Python?

Tags: python, list, append

I know this is basic but google is not helping. I'm currently trying to translate some python to java and I came across `list.append([x][i])`. No `,` no nothing. Just like that. Can anyone explain what x, and i represent in this `.append`

Example:

```
from math import log

def number_of_steps(weight):
    return int(log(weight * 2, 3)) + 1


def instruction_index(n, weight):
    offset = (3 ** n - 1) / 2

    corrected = int((weight + offset) / 3 ** n)

    return corrected % 3


def answer(weight):
   instructions = []

    steps = number_of_steps(weight)

    for n in xrange(steps):

    i = instruction_index(n, weight)

    instructions.append(['-', 'R', 'L'][i])

    return instructions
```

Comment: I am doing the foobar google challenge and this code compiled fine, I'll post the example above

Comment: It's grabbing the `i`th index of `x` after it's been added to an empty list.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Thank's I get it now.

Answer (score 3):

1. It is creating a single list `[x]` with element `x`;
2. Then, it is accessing element under index `i` of array.

Following code try to expand this syntax:

```
l = [x]
list.append(l[i])
```

I don't know nothing about the context of call, if it is inside a loop or something. If you can edit you post with context, it may clarify us.

On your real code, it happens on line:

```
instructions.append(['-', 'R', 'L'][i])
```

In this case, depending on the value of i, it will return `-`, `R` or `L`, or a invalid index error in the case of `i` is greater than array length (not in this application, because it is calculated based on 3).

Comment: So what your saying is it's adding element i of x ?

Comment: Is it clear? I tried to explain firstly based on python syntax, only. After, using your application code.

Comment: Yea I got it. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

It creates a list from the variable x and appends its value at the the index i to the original list.